# tensorflow tf.maximum(0, x) returns error

Tags: tensorflow

When trying to use `tf.maximum` as one would expect:

```
loss = tf.maximum(0, basic_loss)
```

this error is obtained

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py
>   in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
>       489                 as_ref=input_arg.is_ref,
>   --> 490                 preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
>       491           except TypeError as err:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
>   in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref,
>   preferred_dtype)
>       740         if ret is None:
>   --> 741           ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
>       742
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
>   in _TensorTensorConversionFunction(t, dtype, name, as_ref)
>       613         "Tensor conversion requested dtype %s for Tensor with dtype %s: %r"
>   --> 614         % (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
>       615   return t
>
> ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with
>   dtype float32: 'Tensor("add_13:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         5               tf.random_normal([3, 128], mean=1, stddev=1, seed = 1),
>         6               tf.random_normal([3, 128], mean=3, stddev=4, seed = 1))
>   ----> 7     loss = triplet_loss(y_true, y_pred)
>         8 
>         9     print("loss = " + str(loss.eval()))
>
> in triplet_loss(y_true, y_pred, alpha)
>        26     basic_loss = pos_dist - neg_dist + alpha
>        27     # Step 4: Take the maximum of basic_loss and 0.0. Sum over the training examples.
>   ---> 28     loss = tf.maximum(0, basic_loss)
>        29     ### END CODE HERE ###
>        30
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py
>   in maximum(x, y, name)    1261     A `Tensor`. Has the same type as
>   `x`.    1262   """
>   -> 1263   result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Maximum", x=x, y=y, name=name)    1264   return result    1265
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py
>   in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
>       524                   "%s type %s of argument '%s'." %
>       525                   (prefix, dtypes.as_dtype(attrs[input_arg.type_attr]).name,
>   --> 526                    inferred_from[input_arg.type_attr]))
>       527 
>       528           types = [values.dtype]
>
> TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Maximum' Op has type float32 that does not
>   match type int32 of argument 'x'.

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The tensor flow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/maximum) does not state that the `maximum` function is **non-commutative**.

It works only if the type of the 1st argument is a Tensor, but not if its type is int.

Need to call this function with replaced positions of the arguments for constants:

`tf.maximum(basic_loss, 0)`

instead of

`tf.maximum(0, basic_loss)`